# Cross Join in dplyr in R

Tags: r, dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
cust_time<-data.frame(cid=c("c1","c2","c3","c4","c5"),ts=c(2,7,11,13,17))
#I want to do a cross join on self, preferable in dplyr else base package is Ok
#But w/o renaming header names
#Currently I have to create a duplicate cust_time to do this.
cust_time.1<-rename(cust_time,cid1=cid,ts1=ts)
merge(cust_time,cust_time.1,by=NULL)

#Later I will want to do cross join within the grouped region
cust_time <-mutate(cust_time,ts.bucket=ts%/%10)
#If using duplicate tables, not sure, how to do the below
#group_by(cust_time,ts.bucket) %>%
#do cross join within this bucket
```

Basically, I want to do a cross self-join on a table but since I cant a dplyr solution, I used the base package. But it requires me to rename all the columns. However, I later want to be able do a cross-join at a grouped level and this is where I am stumbling.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: there is no `ts.bucket` in `cust_time`

Comment: You could try `do.call(data.table::CJ, cust_time)`

Comment: @DavidArenburg, that's just `expand.grid(cust_time)`, isn't it?

Comment: @docendodiscimus yes, but gazillion times faster... or `tidyr::complete(cust_time, cid, ts)` probably if we already into it...

Comment: @DavidArenburg, I know. What I mean is, it doesn't correspond to the output that OP creates with his `merge`

Comment: @docendodiscimus looks exactly the same to me... the third and the fourth columns are redundant as they are there because OP duplicated the columns. At least this is how I read it.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, that's strange. I get a 4 column table with the merge but only 2 columns with your CJ approach or expand.grid as I mentioned

Comment: @DavidArenburg, so it's not exactly the same

Comment: @mtoto : I have edited that now.

Comment: @DavidArenburg : Hi both the do.call(data.table::CJ, cust_time) and tidyr::complete(cust_time, cid, ts) are completely different to my output. They are not doing any cross joins.

Comment: I think you want: `cust_time %>% rowwise %>% do(data.frame(., cust_time))`?

Comment: `CJ` stands for: (C)ross (J)oin and they are returning your exact output.

Comment: @DavidArenburg They aren't the same.  Your suggestions give the Cartesian product of the columns `cust_time$cid` and `cust_time$ts`, whereas the OP's example gives the Cartesian product of the rows of `cust_time`.  ("Cartesian product of the rows" is the usual meaning of "cross join", at least in SQL terminology.)

Comment: Note for instance that if you pipe the OP's output to `%>% dplyr::distinct(cid, ts)` you get 5 rows, whereas your suggestions above would give 25 rows.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You just need a dummy column to join on:

```
cust_time$k <- 1
cust_time %>% 
  inner_join(cust_time, by='k') %>%
  select(-k)
```

Or if you don't want to modify your original dataframe:

```
cust_time %>%
  mutate(k = 1) %>%
  replicate(2, ., simplify=FALSE) %>%
  Reduce(function(a, b) inner_join(a, b, by='k'), .) %>%
  select(-k)
```

Answer (score 31):

As of `dplyr` version 1.0, you can do a cross join by specifying `by = character()`:

```
cust_time %>% full_join(cust_time, by = character())
```

Comment: This is the best solution! If you have some other steps before `full_join` you use do `... %>% full_join(., ., by = character())`.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution that is completely `dplyr`-compatible.  It shares many of the same ideas as attitude_stool's solution but has the advantage of only being one line.

```
require(magrittr)  # for the %<>% operator

# one line:
(cust_time %<>% mutate(foo = 1)) %>% 
        full_join(cust_time, by = 'foo') %>% 
        select(-foo)
```

Comment: Without modification of the original data: `cust_time %>% mutate(foo=1) %>% full_join(.,., by="foo") %>% select(-foo)`

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr 1.1.0`, you can now use `cross_join`:

```r
cross_join(cust_time, cust_time)
```

Using `by = character()` is deprecated under `dplyr 1.1.0` and above:

> Warning message: Using `by = character()` to perform a cross join was
> deprecated in dplyr 1.1.0. ℹ Please use `cross_join()` instead.