# R. Run optimization function in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, mathematical-optimization

I have a data frame df1 in R that looks like this (all values were chosen randomly but approximate values from real data):

```
A B    C    D   E   F      G     H
a 0.04 0.01 50  70  0.01   ...   0.0002
b 0.03 0.1  49  69  0.01   ...   0.0003
c 0.03 0.02 51  71  0.005  ...   0.004
d 0.04 0.02 50  70  0.006  ...   0.0005
```

G is obtained in this way:

```
# Equation 1:

G = (B - C)^2 - B*(1 - B)/(D- 1) - C*(1 - C)/(E - 1)

library(dplyr)
df2 = df1 %>% mutate(G = (B - C)^2 - B*(1 - B)/(D- 1) - C*(1 - C)/(E - 1))
```

I want to create a new column G1 applying an optimization function in each row.

G1 is obtained using equation 1, but replacing B by H. H is obtained using Equation 2:

```
# Equation 2:

H = (B - z*F)/(1 - z)
```

I would like to create a new column Z, with the value of z, ranging from 0 to 1 (step=0.01) which produces the lowest G1.

I expect to get something like this:

```
A B    C    D   E   F      G     H      G1  Z
a 0.04 0.01 50  70  0.01   ...   0.0002 ... ...
b 0.03 0.1  49  69  0.01   ...   0.0003 ... ...
c 0.03 0.02 51  71  0.005  ...   0.004  ... ...
d 0.04 0.02 50  70  0.006  ...   0.0005 ... ...
```

**EDIT:** (clarification)

My question is how to find the z that produces the lowest G1 given H (and the conditions referred above) and also get G1.

Comment: Why not create *H* first, then *G*, then *G1*? In R you can run arithmetic across columns. Not clear what you mean by *Z*.

Comment: If your dataframe is named `df`, then just do `df$G = (df$B - df$C)^2 - df$B...`

Comment: Hello @DanY, yes, I know how to do what you mention.  I need to get G1 given H and the lowest z. Please see edit

Comment: What do you mean by "the lowest G1"? It will be different in every row, right? Is there a target, you wan to minimize, say, sum squared error between G1 and something? Or minimize the sum of G1? The product of G1? The sum of G1^2? Also, you refer a few times to "the lowest `z`" - do you mean the value of `z` that corresponds to the minimized (unspecified function of) `G1`? Or something else?

Comment: I'd recommend looking into `optim` rather than trying to code your own optimization routine, but `optim` works to minimize a *single value*, and as explained in my previous comment I don't understand what you're trying to minimize.

Comment: Yes @Gregor, it will be different in every row. I just need to get, for each row, the value of z that produces the lowest value of G1 given H. The target is just the value of G1.

Comment: I may have a solution for you. Are those posted `H` values correct given the example values? Or just unrelated numbers you threw in there.

Comment: Thank you @Parfait, they are unrelated numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider looping through multiples of 0.01 from 0.01 to 1 through your *G1* function with all other parameters supplied by data frame. Then take the minimum of the returned vector of values.

Specifically, you can set up a function that passes in the row wise values using `mapply` (the elementwise iterator function) and returns the minimum for *z* value.

**Data** *(F is changed to F_ to avoid issues with FALSE)*

```
txt <- "A B    C    D   E   F_
a 0.04 0.01 50  70  0.01  
b 0.03 0.1  49  69  0.01  
c 0.03 0.02 51  71  0.005 
d 0.04 0.02 50  70  0.006"

df <- read.table(text=txt, header=TRUE)
```

**Function**

```
main <- function(B_param, C_param, D_param, E_param, F_param) {

  # EXTENDED G1 FUNCTION (WITH HELPER H)
  func <- function(z) {
    H <- (B_param - z*F_param)/(1 - z)
    G1 <- (H - C_param)^2 - H*(1 - H)/(D_param- 1) - C_param*(1 - C_param)/(E_param - 1)
  }

  # ITERATE THROUGH 0.01 MULTIPLES 
  tmp <- sapply(seq(0.01, 0.99, 0.01), func)

  # RETURN Z AT THE MINIMUM OF VECTOR OF VALUES
  min_z <- seq(0.01, 0.99, 0.01)[which.min(tmp)]

  return(min_z)
}
```

**Data frame call** *(using base's `within` to add new columns)*

```
final_df <- within(df, {

  G <- (B - C)^2 - B*(1 - B)/(D- 1) - C*(1 - C)/(E - 1)

  # CALCULATE z BY PASSING COLUMN VALUES ELEMENTWISE
  z <- mapply(main, B, C, D, E, F_)
  H <- (B - z*F_)/(1 - z)
  G1 <- (H - C)^2 - H*(1 - H)/(D- 1) - C*(1 - C)/(E - 1)      
})

options(scipen=999)

# RE-ORDER COLUMNS
final_df[order(names(final_df))]
#   A    B    C  D  E    F_              G             G1          H    z
# 1 a 0.04 0.01 50 70 0.010 -0.00002715173 -0.00001456576 0.04030303 0.01
# 2 b 0.03 0.10 49 69 0.010  0.00297022059 -0.00326311275 0.11000000 0.80
# 3 c 0.03 0.02 51 71 0.005 -0.00076200000 -0.00076163193 0.03025253 0.01
# 4 d 0.04 0.02 50 70 0.006 -0.00066773144 -0.00066032187 0.04034343 0.01
```

Comment: Hello @Parfait, there is something in the "main" function that is not completely clear to me. Where is it indicated to return the lowest G1  value given z?. In the Python script you have "return G1". Don't I need something similar in "main"?. Thank you very much

Comment: In R, `return()` is optional as functions will return the last line regardless (i.e., `G1` object).

Comment: Hello @Parfait, I realised there is a mistake in your solution. I asked for z values in intervals of 0.01. However, if I replace seq(0, 1) by seq(0, 1, 0.01) in the "main" function, I get exactly the same z results (please look at the z column with z values < 0.01. May I ask you your opinion?. I am sorry for realising this only now. Thanks very much and I apologise for the inconvenient.

Comment: The *interval* in R's `optimize` takes only endpoints, so `seq(0,1)` was read as `c(0,1)`. To run through each intervals, consider building a vector/list then return min of this vector/list. See update with R `sapply` and Python list comprehension.

Comment: Hi @Parfait. I am still getting z values < 0.01, as the "z" column of final_df shows (R script). Thank you very much

Comment: I thought you wanted to search within 0.01 intervals. If not, simply run all multiples of 0.01 through *G1* function then take the minimum. No need for `optimize` which looks for extrema points between intervals.

Comment: Hello @Parfait, this is the last question, I am sorry for bothering you again. When I run your code with that example it does perfectly it fine. However, with my real data (a data frame), I get: "Error in z * F_ : non-numeric argument to binary operator" in the "Data frame call" section of the script. I converted F_ to numeric using as.numeric(), but I get the same error message. Do you have an idea of what could be causing this?. Thanks again

Comment: Something is wrong with your function return affecting *z* value. Run only the `mapply` call and check results. You might be getting back `NULL` as I changed main's last line to `return(NULL)` and received your same error. In fact, I even made one column all `NA` and one row all `NA` and both times received your error. Check if any column or row are entirely missing. See `df[complete.cases(df),]` for rows.

Comment: Thank you @Parfait, I followed all your suggestions but I am still getting the same message.

Comment: Please post the dput dump of your data frame: `dput(df)`. If too large use pastebin.com, GitHub gist, or rextester.com.

Comment: Hello @Parfait, I am sorry for bothering you again with this issue. I would like to perform the tame task as described but with the conditions that 0 > H > 1 and that (1 - z) > 0. May I ask you how to do it?. Many thanks

Comment: Try applying those two in `if ... else` conditions inside the function. And if those conditions occur have function return `NA` so the `which.min(tmp)` disregards it.

Comment: Thank you @Parfait

Answer (score 1):

Add the `z` column, make the calculation, find the minimum within each group. As in the question [Cross join with dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35422527/903061) we add a dummy column to join on to make a cross join.

```
df2 %>% mutate(cj = 1) %>%
  full_join(data.frame(cj = 1, z = seq(0, 1, by = 0.01)) %>%
  select(-cj) %>%
  mutate(H = (B - z*F)/(1 - z),
         G1 = (H - C)^2 - H*(1 - H)/(D- 1) - C*(1 - C)/(E - 1)) %>%
  group_by(A, B, C, D, E, F) %>%
  arrange(G1) %>%
  slice(1)
```

Comment: Thank you @Gregor, your solution works very nice as well, but Parfait posted the solution first