# R. Add conditions within optimization function

Tags: r, dataframe, optimization

I have the following optimization function, similar as this one:
[R. Run optimization function in data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53343974/r-run-optimization-function-in-data-frame):

```
main <- function(p1, p2, n1, n2, pE) {

  # FIND MINIMUM a
  func <- function(a) {
    Mopt <- (p1-a*pE)/(1-a) 
    f_n <- (Mopt-p2)^2-Mopt*(1-Mopt)/(n1-1) - p2*(1-p2)/(n2-1)
    f_d <- Mopt*(1-p2)+p2*(1-Mopt)
    f_v <- f_n/f_d
    }
    opt <- optimize(func, seq(0, 1,by=0.01), maximum=FALSE)$minimum
  }
```

Here, the arguments of "main" are columns from a data frame. The function returns the minimum value of "a" required to get the minimum f_v value. I would like to add some conditions to the function, or in other words, to force a certain objects to acquire values within a certain range, in order to get the minimum f_v. For instance, Mopt must follow:

```
0 < Mopt < 1
```

and (1 - a) must follow:

```
(1 - a) > 0.
```

I am not sure how to do this in the context of an optimization.

Comment: return `Inf` within `func` if constraints are broken?

Comment: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/constrOptim.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think simply add the condition would work. Code might be like this.

```
func <- function(a) {
  a = min(a, 1-1e-7);
  Mopt <- max(min((p1-a*pE)/(1-a), 1-1e-7), 1e-7);
  #here means a<1 and 0<Mopt<1. 1e-7 ensures the inequality. It can be 1e-6 or 1e-8 depends on the precision you need

  f_n <- (Mopt-p2)^2-Mopt*(1-Mopt)/(n1-1) - p2*(1-p2)/(n2-1)
  f_d <- Mopt*(1-p2)+p2*(1-Mopt)
  f_v <- f_n/f_d
  }
opt <- seq(0, 1, 1e-7)[which.min(sapply(seq(0, 1, 1e-7), func))]
```

Addition:
Code above would return the right `$objective` but may fail in searching `minimum`. To search minimum, the function should be.

```
func <- function(a) {
  if ((1-a)<1e-7) return(Inf);
  #Ensure the optimization is reached in the range of condition

  Mopt <-(p1-a*pE)/(1-a);
  if (Mopt<1e-7 || Mopt>(1-1e-7)) return(Inf);
  #Ensure the optimization is reached in the range of condition

  f_n <- (Mopt-p2)^2-Mopt*(1-Mopt)/(n1-1) - p2*(1-p2)/(n2-1)
  f_d <- Mopt*(1-p2)+p2*(1-Mopt)
  f_v <- f_n/f_d
  }
opt <- seq(0, 1, 1e-7)[which.min(sapply(seq(0, 1, 1e-7), func))]
```

It is very time consuming but available when you do not need to repeat the computation for many times.

Comment: Hi @Xinz, thank you very much for your response. When I have these parameter values:  p1=0.002577, p2=0, n1= 388, n2=390, pE=0.01282; I get a=0.9999339 and  Mopt = -154.933, but Mopt should not reach this value

Comment: @Lucas it seems that function `optimize` is based on a heuristic algorithm and continuous function is needed. so I suggest you to use an exhaustion method as in the reversed answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Xinz. Your script runs very slow indeed. It has been running for >3 hours already. Would it be OK if I change seq(0,1,1e-7) to seq(0,1,1e-4), for example?

Comment: @Lucas yes, it totally depends on the precision you need.