# R group rows conditional by rowwise comparisons in a scalable way

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to group rows in a dataset based on a rowwise comparison or matching of four different variables in a way that it can be computed fast. The dataset has the following shape:

| id | start | start_sep | end | end_sep |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 | F | 1 |
| 2 | B | 0 | G | 0 |
| 3 | D | 1 | H | 0 |
| 4 | D | 1 | J | 0 |
| 5 | E | 0 | K | 0 |
| 6 | F | 1 | L | 0 |
| 7 | A | 1 | O | 0 |
| 8 | H | 0 | P | 0 |
| 9 | A | 1 | P | 1 |

Specifically, I would like to group those rows that share the same value in either start<>end, end<>start, start<>start, or end<>end and have a matching value (>0) in the related start_sep and end_sep column. start_sep and end_sep are basically an additional check if the first match is correct. Groups usually contain matches of two rows, but can be of any number in size if a rows start and end matches more than one. Matches are always unique, so there won't be a matching conflict of two rows with the same matching start and end combination.

Here is a little illustration of potential match combinations in the columns 'start' and 'end':

[image: Possible match combinations]

For the example above, the expected result would be:

| id | start | start_sep | end | end_sep | group_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 | F | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | B | 0 | G | 0 | NA |
| 3 | D | 1 | H | 0 | 2 |
| 4 | D | 1 | J | 0 | 2 |
| 5 | E | 0 | K | 0 | NA |
| 6 | F | 1 | L | 0 | 1 |
| 7 | A | 0 | O | 1 | 3 |
| 8 | O | 1 | P | 0 | 3 |
| 9 | A | 1 | P | 0 | 1 |

In this sense matches can occure within a row

I can do this with a slow for loop and a set of conditions, ie., selecting a row (if group_id is NA) finding all matches (based on conditions describing possible match combinations) and asign group_id. But since my dataset has 1 million plus rows, this is a very slow process. See below an example for a single case example below:

```
#create data.frame
df <- data.frame (id = c("1", "2", "3","4","5","6","7","8","9"),
                  start  = c("A", "B", "D","D","E","F","A","O","A"),
                  start_sep = c("1", "0", "1","1","0","1","0","1","1"),
                  end = c("F", "G", "H", "J","K","L","O","P","P"),
                  end_sep = c("1", "0", "0","0","0","0","1","0","0"),
                  gid = 0
                  )

#extract a single row
i <- df[1,]

#find all matching rows and asign row id as group id
y <-  df[ which( i[,6] == 0 &
  (i[,2] == df[,2] & i[,3] == df[,3] | 
  i[,4] == df[,4] & i[,5] == df[,5] |
  i[,2] == df[,4] & i[,3] == df[,5] |
  i[,4] == df[,2] & i[,5] == df[,3])
  ),] %>% mutate(gid = recode(gid, '0' = i[,1]) )

View(y)
```

I am wondering whether there might be a straight forward way with `lapply` or `dplyr` (e.g. `mutate()`, `group_by()`, `rowwise()`, `cur_group_id()`) that is fast, or maybe a much more efficient way than the approch outlined above?

Comment: Also, your sample code doesn't work.  There are only four columsn in your `df`, yet you attempt to select a `5`th and `6`th column (`i[,6]`, `df[,5]`, etc.), which yields the error: `Error in '[.data.frame'(i, , 6) : undefined columns selected`.

Comment: Hi @Greg, thanks for flagging this. I forgot the 'id' column, but have updated this now and it should work. Sorry!

Comment: No worries! Taking a look now...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are two solutions with [**`dplyr`**](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org) and [**`data.table`**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table) respectively.  Each package [vectorizes its operations](https://bookdown.org/rdpeng/rprogdatascience/vectorized-operations.html), so these solutions should be *far* faster than your loop; and the **`data.table`** solution should be the fastest of them all.

**Let me know how each solution works for you!**

## Note

To identify the group to which each row belongs, we use the *earliest* row that it "matches"; where "matching" rows are defined as those that

> share the same value in either `start`<>`end`, `end`<>`start`, `start`<>`start`, or `end`<>`end` and have a matching value (`>0`) in the related `start_sep` and `end_sep` column.

For a smaller dataset, it would be simple enough to perform a [`CROSS JOIN`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62277055) and then filter by your criteria. However, for a dataset with over 1 million rows, its `CROSS JOIN` would easily max out the available memory at over 1 *trillion* rows, so I had to find a different technique.

To wit, I use [`paste0()`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/paste.html) to generate "artificial" keys. Here `start` and `start_sep` are combined into `start_label`, while `end` and `end_sep` are combined into `end_label`. Now we can directly [`match()`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/match.html) on a single column like `start_label`; rather than sifting every *possible* match across a *set* of columns like {`start`, `start_sep`}.

**This approach assumes that in those `*` and `*_sep` columns:**

1. **every distinct value can be represented as a distinct string;**
2. **the separator `"|"` is absent from that string.**

## Solution 1: `dplyr`

Once you load **`dplyr`**

```
library(dplyr)


# ...
# Code to generate 'df'.
# ...
```

this workflow should do the trick. Note that group IDs *must* be calculated *before* the `JOIN`; since [`cur_group_id()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/context.html) would otherwise "misidentify" the `NA`s as a group unto themselves.

```
df %>%
  mutate(
    # Create an artificial key for matching.
    start_label = paste0(start, " | ", start_sep),
    end_label   = paste0(end,   " | ", end_sep  ),
    
    # Identify the earliest row where each match is found.
    start_to_start = match(start_label, start_label),
    start_to_end   = match(start_label, end_label  ),
    end_to_start   = match(end_label  , start_label),
    end_to_end     = match(end_label  , end_label  )
  ) %>%
  
  # Include only rows meeting the criteria: remove any...
  filter(
  # ...without a match...
  #                   |-------------------------------------------|
    (start_sep > 0 & !(is.na(start_to_start) & is.na(start_to_end))) |
    (end_sep   > 0 & !(is.na(end_to_start  ) & is.na(end_to_end  )))
  #  |-----------|
  # ...that corresponds to a positive '*_sep'.
  ) %>%
  
  # For each row, identify the earliest of ALL its matches.
  mutate(
    match_id = pmin(
      start_to_start, start_to_end, end_to_start, end_to_end,
      na.rm = TRUE
    )
  ) %>%

  # Keep only the 'id' of each row, along with a 'group_id' for its earliest match.
  group_by(match_id) %>%
  transmute(
    id,
    group_id = cur_group_id()
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  
  # Map the original rows to their 'group_id's; with blanks (NAs) for no match.
  right_join(df, by = "id") %>%
  
  # Format into final form.
  select(id, start, start_sep, end, end_sep, group_id) %>%
  arrange(id)
```

### Results

Please note that your sample data is inconsistent, so I have reconstructed my own `df`:

```
df <- structure(list(
    id = 1:9,
    start = c("A", "B", "D", "D", "E", "F", "A", "O", "A"),
    start_sep = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L),
    end = c("F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "L", "O", "P", "P"),
    end_sep = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L)
  ),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA, -9L)
)
```

Given said `df`, the workflow should yield the following `tibble`:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 6
     id start start_sep end   end_sep group_id
  <int> <chr>     <int> <chr>   <int>    <int>
1     1 A             1 F           1        1
2     2 B             0 G           0       NA
3     3 D             1 H           0        2
4     4 D             1 J           0        2
5     5 E             0 K           0       NA
6     6 F             1 L           0        1
7     7 A             0 O           1        3
8     8 O             1 P           0        3
9     9 A             1 P           0        1
```

## Solution 2: `data.table`

Here is essentially the same logic, but implemented in **`data.table`**.

```
library(data.table)


# ...
# Code to generate 'df'.
# ...


# Convert 'df' to a data.table.
df <- as.data.table(df)
```

Again, note that group IDs *must* be calculated *before* the `JOIN`; since [`.GRP`](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/reference/special-symbols.html#details) would otherwise "misidentify" the `NA`s as a group unto themselves.

```
# Use 'id' as the key for efficient JOINs.
setkey(df, id

# Calculate the label and matching columns as before.
)[, c("start_label", "end_label") := .(
  paste0(start, " | ", start_sep),
  paste0(end  , " | ", end_sep  )
)][, c("start_to_start", "start_to_end", "end_to_start", "end_to_end") := .(
  match(start_label, start_label),
  match(start_label, end_label  ),
  match(end_label  , start_label),
  match(end_label  , end_label  )

# Filter by criteria as before.
)][
  (start_sep > 0 & !(is.na(start_to_start) & is.na(start_to_end))) |
  (end_sep   > 0 & !(is.na(end_to_start  ) & is.na(end_to_end  )))

# Generate the 'group_id' as before.
,][, .(id, match_id = pmin(
  start_to_start, start_to_end, end_to_start, end_to_end,
  na.rm = TRUE
))][,
  ("group_id") := .GRP,
  by = .(match_id)

# Perform the mapping (RIGHT JOIN) as before...
][
  df,
  # ...and select the desired columns.
  .(id, start, start_sep, end, end_sep, group_id)
]
```

### Results

With `df` as before, this solution should yield the following `data.table`:

```
   id start start_sep end end_sep group_id
1:  1     A         1   F       1        1
2:  2     B         0   G       0       NA
3:  3     D         1   H       0        2
4:  4     D         1   J       0        2
5:  5     E         0   K       0       NA
6:  6     F         1   L       0        1
7:  7     A         0   O       1        3
8:  8     O         1   P       0        3
9:  9     A         1   P       0        1
```

## Performance

At scale, the **`data.table` solution** should be **proportionately faster** than the **`dplyr`** solution; but both should be quite fast.

On the massive dataset `big_data`, a `data.frame` with over 1 million rows

```
# Find every combination of variables...
big_df <- expand.grid(
  start = LETTERS,
  start_sep = 0:1,
  end = LETTERS,
  end_sep = 0:1
)

# ...and repeat until there are (at least) 1 million...
n_comb <- nrow(big_df)
n_rep <- ceiling(1000000/n_comb)

# ...with unique IDs.
big_df <- data.frame(
  id = 1:(n_comb * n_rep),
  start     = rep(big_df$start    , n_rep),
  start_sep = rep(big_df$start_sep, n_rep),
  end       = rep(big_df$end      , n_rep),
  end_sep   = rep(big_df$end_sep  , n_rep)
)
```

we can measure the relative performances of each solution at scale

```
library(microbenchmark)

performances <- microbenchmark(
  # Repeat test 50 times, for reliability.
  times = 50,
  
  # Solution 1: "dplyr".
  solution_1 = {
    big_df %>%
      mutate(
        start_label = paste0(start, " | ", start_sep),
        end_label   = paste0(end,   " | ", end_sep  ),
        start_to_start = match(start_label, start_label),
        start_to_end   = match(start_label, end_label  ),
        end_to_start   = match(end_label  , start_label),
        end_to_end     = match(end_label  , end_label  )
      ) %>%
      filter(
        (start_sep > 0 & !(is.na(start_to_start) & is.na(start_to_end))) |
        (end_sep   > 0 & !(is.na(end_to_start  ) & is.na(end_to_end  )))
      ) %>%
      mutate(match_id = pmin(
        start_to_start, start_to_end, end_to_start, end_to_end,
        na.rm = TRUE
      )) %>%
      group_by(match_id) %>%
      transmute(id, group_id = cur_group_id()) %>%
      ungroup() %>%
      right_join(big_df, by = "id") %>%
      select(id, start, start_sep, end, end_sep, group_id) %>%
      arrange(id)
  },
  
  # Solution 2: "data.table"
  solution_2 = {
    big_dt <- as.data.table(big_df)
    
    setkey(big_dt, id)[, c("start_label", "end_label") := .(
      paste0(start, " | ", start_sep),
      paste0(end  , " | ", end_sep  )
    )][, c("start_to_start", "start_to_end", "end_to_start", "end_to_end") := .(
      match(start_label, start_label),
      match(start_label, end_label  ),
      match(end_label  , start_label),
      match(end_label  , end_label  )
    )][
      (start_sep > 0 & !(is.na(start_to_start) & is.na(start_to_end))) |
      (end_sep   > 0 & !(is.na(end_to_start  ) & is.na(end_to_end  )))
    ,][, .(id, match_id = pmin(
      start_to_start, start_to_end, end_to_start, end_to_end,
      na.rm = TRUE
    ))][, ("group_id") := .GRP, by = .(match_id)
    ][big_dt, .(id, start, start_sep, end, end_sep, group_id)]
  }
)
```

which I have tabulated here:

```
#> performances

Unit: milliseconds
       expr      min       lq      mean   median        uq       max neval
 solution_1 880.1443 972.9289 1013.2868 997.5746 1059.9192 1186.8743    50
 solution_2 581.2570 606.7222  649.9858 650.2422  679.4404  734.3966    50
```

---

By converting from time to speed

```
library(formattable)

performances %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  group_by(expr) %>%
  summarize(t_mean = mean(time)) %>%
  transmute(
    solution = expr,
    # Invert time to get speed; and normalize % by longest time.
    advantage = percent(max(t_mean)/t_mean - 1)
  )
```

we estimate that the **`data.table`** solution is (on average) about 50% faster than the **`dplyr`** solution.

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  solution   advantage 
  <fct>      <formttbl>
1 solution_1 0.00%     
2 solution_2 55.89%
```

Comment: Many thanks @Greg! This not only solved my problem brilliantly, but it is an examplary answer and really the reason I love stackoverflow. My data.table knowledge is limited so your side by side solutions area a great learning opportunity. Thanks also for your performance evaluation. Highly appreciated!

Comment: @krenz Thank you for the kind words!  I'm guessing the fastest solution on your end was also **`data.table`**?

Comment: Yes, your data.table solution was for me as well the fastest. Though, the speed increase from your dplyr solution makes this already an applicable option, which might also be useful for some OSX users struggeling to install data.table correctly–due to the lack of a default OpenMP runtime in the clang compiler.

Comment: @krenz Thanks for elaborating!  Your comment should prove useful to further viewers.  :)