# R - Add a column on a dataset based on values from another dataset

Tags: r

I have a dataset (df1) with a column that contains Remaining_points for each owner

Df1:

```
Id      Owner   Remaining_points
00001   John    18
00008   Paul    34
00011   Alba    52
00004   Martha  67
```

And another one with different id’s that contains points
Df2

```
Id      Points
00025   17
00076   35
00089   51
00092   68
```

I need to add to df2 a Owner column with most similar Remaining_points on df1

Desired dataframe:

```
Id      Points  Owner
00025   17      John
00076   35      Paul
00089   51      Alba
00092   68      Martha
```

Please, could anyone help me on this?
I’m used to work with dplyr but any solution would be very appreciated.

Comment: The "with most similar `Remaining_points` on df1" part seems like the important piece of this question.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: And please make the example easy to replicate.  Use something like `dput()` or the datapasta package to provide something like

```
ds_1 <- 
  tibble::tribble(
    ~Id    , ~Owner    , ~Remaining_points,
    "00001", "John"    , 18L,
    "00008", "Paul"    , 34L,
    "00011", "Alba"    , 52L,
    "00004", "Martha"  , 67L
  )
```

Comment: Sure, sorry for the inconvenience. With "most similar" i wanna say "the most approximate value".

Comment: How about "closest absolute value"?   It looks like @tacoman did that below.  (Make sure you accept his post if it addresses/solves your question.)

Answer (score 2):

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c("00001", "00008", "00011", "00004"),
                  Owner = c("John", "Paul", "Alba", "Martha"),
                  Remaining_points = c(18, 34, 52, 67))

df2 <- data.frame(ID = c("00025", "00076", "00089", "00092"),
                  Points = c(17, 35, 51, 68))

ind <- which(apply(abs(outer(df1$Remaining_points,df2$Points, "-")), 2, function(x) x == min(x)), arr.ind = TRUE)
df2$Owner <- df1$Owner[ind[,1]]
df2
     ID Points  Owner
1 00025     17   John
2 00076     35   Paul
3 00089     51   Alba
4 00092     68 Martha
```

Answer (score 1):

@tacoman's works well.  But I couldn't resist including a dplyr version.  The [cross join](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35406535/1082435) is doing a similar job to @tacoman's `outer()`.

```r
df1 <- data.frame(ID_1 = c("00001", "00008", "00011", "00004"),
                  Owner = c("John", "Paul", "Alba", "Martha"),
                  Remaining_points = c(18, 34, 52, 67))

df2 <- data.frame(ID_2 = c("00025", "00076", "00089", "00092"),
                  Points = c(17, 35, 51, 68))


df1 |> 
  dplyr::full_join(df2, by = character()) |>    # This is essentially a cross join b/c no key is used.
  dplyr::mutate(
    distance  = abs(Points - Remaining_points), # Find the difference in all possibilities
  ) |> 
  dplyr::group_by(ID_2) |>                      # Isolate each ID in its own sub-dataset 
  dplyr::mutate(
    rank      = dplyr::row_number(distance),    # Rank the distances. The closest will be '1'.
  ) |> 
  dplyr::filter(rank == 1L) |>                  # Keep only the closest
  dplyr::ungroup() |> 
  dplyr::select(
    ID_2,
    Points,
    Owner
  )
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  ID_2  Points Owner 
  <chr>  <dbl> <chr> 
1 00025     17 John  
2 00076     35 Paul  
3 00089     51 Alba  
4 00092     68 Martha
```

This is the intermediate result (before removing the extra rows and columns):

```
# A tibble: 16 x 7
# Groups:   ID_2 [4]
   ID_1  Owner  Remaining_points ID_2  Points distance  rank
   <chr> <chr>             <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>    <dbl> <int>
 1 00001 John                 18 00025     17        1     1 # <- closest for John
 2 00001 John                 18 00076     35       17     2
 3 00001 John                 18 00089     51       33     4
 4 00001 John                 18 00092     68       50     4
 5 00008 Paul                 34 00025     17       17     2
 6 00008 Paul                 34 00076     35        1     1 # <- closest for Paul
 7 00008 Paul                 34 00089     51       17     3
 8 00008 Paul                 34 00092     68       34     3
 9 00011 Alba                 52 00025     17       35     3
10 00011 Alba                 52 00076     35       17     3
11 00011 Alba                 52 00089     51        1     1 # <- closest for Alba
12 00011 Alba                 52 00092     68       16     2
13 00004 Martha               67 00025     17       50     4
14 00004 Martha               67 00076     35       32     4
15 00004 Martha               67 00089     51       16     2
16 00004 Martha               67 00092     68        1     1 # <- closest for Martha
```